# How to clear cache over sftp in symfony 2?

Tags: symfony

I have only sftp access. I have uploaded changes on server using sftp put command. But as usual I have to clear cache to reflect those changes.

So, my question is how can I clear Symfony cache over sftp?

I have tried this: `php app/console cache:clear` and its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. sFTP is still FTP. And you cannot run programs via FTP.

Possible solution would be to use some bundle that will create a web interface for Symfony's console like [CoreSphere/ConsoleBundle](https://github.com/CoreSphere/ConsoleBundle).

Just remember to secure access to this console so nobody but you can use it. ;-)

If you need only `clear:cache` command, you actually can simply remove `/var/cache/prod` content, which should have exactly the same effect.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer.